# Send toast from F#

Tags: windows-8, f#, windows-runtime

I would like to send a `ToastNotification` in the Windows 8.1 style from a F# console application.

Here is my code:

```
let gotMessage message =
    let xdoc = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText03)
    let children = xdoc.ChildNodes
    children.[0 |> uint32].AppendChild(xdoc.CreateTextNode "Message coming") |> ignore
    children.[2 |> uint32].AppendChild(xdoc.CreateTextNode message) |> ignore
    let toast = new ToastNotification(xdoc)
    toast.add_Activated (fun notification _ -> 0 |> ignore) |> ignore
```

But I get the following exception:

First the German:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException wurde nicht behandelt.
Message: Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" ist in Ineedtea.Server.exe aufgetreten.
Zusätzliche Informationen: Die Datei oder Assembly "Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

Now the English

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was not handled.
Message: An exception of type "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" appeared in Ineedtea.Server.exe.
Additional information: The file or assembly "Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or a dependency wasn't found. The system cannot find the file.
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around, I created a C# library and there I wrote the Toaster class.

Check this Github repository for the code :) https://github.com/DerKnerd/ineedtea/tree/master/WinRTMapper